# I have this problem: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection could not be authenticated. Reason: User ID or password invalid

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

So as shown above I get this error message while trying to add values to my Java derby Database. Full error-message is as shown:
run:

```
    at java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Verbindung konnte nicht authentifiziert werden. Grund: Benutzer-ID oder Kennwort ungültig.org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(SqlException.java:325)
    at org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver.connect(ClientAutoloadedDriver.java:177)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at supermarket1.Seller.AddBtnMouseClicked(Seller.java:294)
    at supermarket1.Seller$1.mouseClicked(Seller.java:111)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:278)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6629)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4584)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: ERROR 08004: Verbindung konnte nicht authentifiziert werden. Grund: Benutzer-ID oder Kennwort ungültig.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.mapSecchkcd(NetConnection.java:1158)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.securityCheckComplete(NetConnection.java:947)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseSECCHKRM(NetConnectionReply.java:582)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseSECCHKreply(NetConnectionReply.java:235)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readSecurityCheck(NetConnectionReply.java:74)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(NetConnection.java:787)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(NetConnection.java:724)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowUSRIDPWDconnect(NetConnection.java:553)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(NetConnection.java:355)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(NetConnection.java:210)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.newNetConnection(ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver.connect(ClientAutoloadedDriver.java:170)
```

First sentence of error message means:'Connection could not be authenticated. Reason: user ID or password invalid. '
I don't know where to type in user id or password and the program doesn't ask me to as well.
The source code is underneath, any help would be greeeaaatlyy appreciated.
Since im a total programming noob and im doing this after a yt-tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByLOrDhn7B0&t=15277s    timestamp: 1:26:00), there might be an easy answer to this problem.

```java
package supermarket1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Seller extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    
    public Seller() {
        initComponents();
    }
Connection Con = null;
Statement St = null;
ResultSet Rs = null;
public void SelectSeller()
{
        try {
            Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SuperMarketdb","User1","1234");
            St = Con.createStatement();
            Rs = St.executeQuery("Select * from User1.SELLERTBL");
            SellerTable.setModel(null);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
    
    
    // "Generated Code">  is not shown here because of Redundancy                        
    

                               

    private void DeleteBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        
    }                                         

    private void ClearBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void AddBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        
        if(SellId.getText().isEmpty() || SellName.getText().isEmpty() || SellPas.getText().isEmpty() )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fehlende Informationen");
        }
        else{
        try{
    Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SuperMarketdb","User1","1234");
    PreparedStatement add = Con.prepareStatement("insert into SELLERTBL values(?,?,?,?)");
    
            add.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(SellId.getText()));
            add.setString(2, SellName.getText());
            add.setString(3, SellPas.getText());
            add.setString(4, GenderCb.getSelectedItem().toString());
            int row = add.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Verkäufer erfolgreich hinzugefügt!");
            
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }                                   

    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Seller().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton AddBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton ClearBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton DeleteBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton EditBtn;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> GenderCb;
    private javax.swing.JTextField SellId;
    private javax.swing.JTextField SellName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField SellPas;
    private javax.swing.JTable SellerTable;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I tried everything but since im not an expert I don't know where to start.

Comment: `"User1","1234"` - that's the username and password. The database probably isn't lying to you - those aren't valid.

Comment: @rzwitserloot so what you mean with „The database probably isn't lying to you“ is that "User1","1234" are wrong login data, am I right? I can’t remember to have chosen something else. Is there a way to refactor username and password? Thanks in advance

Comment: The derby DB documentation would cover that.